Constant function optimization
If I have a function fun like:
-- For example, `SomeRecord` can have more than 2 fields,
-- but 20 or 30
data SomeRecord a b = SomeRecord {
  f1 :: a -> b,
  f2 :: a -> b -> Bool
}

fun :: SomeRecord Int Bool
fun = SomeRecord ...

and then I call fun in different places in my program, will the code produced by GHC call fun every time or it will be replaced by some "reference" to this nullary (actually constant) function's result like C compilers do it with constants? Something like "call it for the first time then replace with this value everywhere in any nesting depth" (or GHC could do it without call even), is it possible? Do I need some special compiler flags for it (I use just -O2 currently)?

In GHC, fun will be evaluated only once, but f1 fun someInt will be evaluated once per call. I am unsure about what you are expecting here. Also, you can experiment with Debug.Trace.trace to see what gets evaluated and when (even if that might change depending on optimization)

fun isn't a function at all. It's just a value of type SomeRecord Int Bool. I guess one could ask, due to laziness, if SomeRecord is "called" multiple times, once per use of fun.

I understand the laziness, I don't understand where are saved these thunks/values: some nested contexts? Global value - cached in global namespace maybe... what about modules? ChatGPT says there is "sharing" in GHC and it shares values, but due to transparency on references I expect even local/nested "constants" to be "shared" (evaluated once), but I am not sure.

@RandomB As a first approximation, if you define a name within some scope then any time you refer to the same name within the same scope it's just referring to a single shared value. So if you define a name in the global scope (with a top-level definition like fun), then there's a single value that is shared across all references (and importing top-level definitions from other modules counts as the same runtime global scope for this purpose). This isn't a hard guarantee as the compiler might "de-share" for optimization, but it's intended to optimize; it tries not to make things worse.

In GHC, fun will compile to an object that, when evaluated for the first time, overwrites itself with the evaluated value. This will happen even with no optimizations turned on at all. (Indeed, turning that behavior off is the hard task, not enabling it.)
